# How to do auth without database in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have to make default login in Laravel with: `php artisan make:auth` and I want to add 1 more authentication with API. In this auth API I don't need database for login.

Is there any solution for this case?

I want to make custom provider and guard it but I am stuck at `AlumniAuthProvider.php` on `App\Auth`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Auth;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\User as UserContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;
use App\Auth\User;

class AlumniAuthProvider implements UserProvider {

    public function alumni()
    {           
    }

    public function retrieveById($identifier)
    {
    }

    public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)
    {
    }

    public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token)
    {
    }

    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {
    }

    public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials)
    {       
    }
}
```

and `Alumni.php` on `App\Auth`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Auth;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Alumni implements Authenticatable
{
    public function getAuthIdentifierName()
    {
    }
    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {        
    }

    /**
     * Get the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberToken()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Set the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
    }

    /**
     * Get the column name for the "remember me" token.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
    }
}
```

How could I make this custom API login?

In my opinion this code, which I made, is for second auth, or am I wrong? Maybe is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: I think doing api login without database is a bad idea because everytime the user will login through another system the api call will took place and thats will create more traffic when your system will be live. Better way is to make api call for the first time and store data in the database and afterwards call data from the database when user re-logins.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @parthu_panther, but i use api with response token jwt, is it good to keep it in the database ? and if yes how can i implements that? use session, coockies or store directly on database ? please help ty.

Comment: no worries if you are using java web token. you can set token in session and your user login credentials in the database.

Comment: oh ty for helping me, i will use it

Comment: @parthu_panther,what do you think API login means? Don't you think it is also using database somewhere or other.

Answer (score -2):

I think doing api login without database is a bad idea because everytime the user will login through another system the api call will took place and thats will create more traffic when your system will be live. Better way is to make api call for the first time and store data in the database and afterwards call data from the database when user re-logins.

Comment: if we need to use database after calling an login API what is the point of creating REST API?